# SQL Query only to return min/Max Value for each row

Tags: sql, max, min

I have the below query which returns time clocking ins over a date range,
I need the query to return the min and max clock in time for each clock in date in a new field which i will then be able to calculate time worked.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

```
Select staffid, staffname, clockdate, clocktime
from database
where ClockDate >='2019-01-01'
```

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would help as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the minimum and maximum time per staff per day on each row, use window functions:

```
Select staffid, staffname, clockdate, clocktime,
       min(clocktime) over (partition by staffid, clockdate) as earliest_time,
       max(clocktime) over (partition by staffid, clockdate) as latest_time
from database
where ClockDate >= '2019-01-01';
```